# How do I exclude pre tags from HTML minification using sed?

Tags: sed, regular-expression, html

I am trying to minify HTML using `sed`

My problem: I don't want to minify anything inside `<pre>` tags, but can't make it work..

Here is what I am using:

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s@>\s*<@><@g' $html_file > ${html_file//.html/.minhtml}
```

This minifies everything, including stuff inside pre tags..

I have looked at using `^[pre]` but can't make that work...

I also looked at using `sed /skipme/! s/foo/bar/`:

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba; /<pre>\.*<\/pre>/! s@>\s*<@><@g' $html_file > ${html_file//.html/.minhtml}
```

(...and yes I insist on using `sed`, not some other tool, thanks.)

Comment: I also tried this:

`sed ':a;N;$!ba; /<div class="highlight"><pre>\.*<\/pre><\/div>/! s@>\s*<@><@g' $html_file > ${html_file//.html/.minhtml}`

Comment: Can you please provide a sample html file to run tests against?

Comment: `<div class="highlight">

<pre><span></span> <span class="nv">var</span><span class="o">=</span><span class="s2">"foo"</span>
 <span class="nb">echo</span> <span class="si">${</span><span class="nv">var</span><span class="p">//foo/bar</span><span class="si">}</span> <span class="c1"># outputs 'bar'</span>
</pre>

</div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed ':a;$!{N;ba;};s/@/@a/g;s/\n/@n/g;s/<pre/\n&/g;s/<\/pre>/&\n/g' test.html \
  | sed -r '/(^<pre|<\/pre>$)/!{s/@n//g;s/>\s+</></g;}' \
  | sed ':a;$!{N;ba;};s/\n//g;s/@n/\n/g;s/@a/@/g' >min.html
```

From [sed scratch pad -- A thread of sed examples](http://murga-linux.com/puppy/viewtopic.php?p=1048208#1048208).

Answer (score 2):

You are aware that regular expressions are the wrong tool for HTML parsing, that it's easy to create edge cases to make a script fail, but you insist in using the wrong tool? Okay, then.

Let's look at cases to be covered: There can be

- lines without any preformatted text (further called `pre`),
- a line of `pre`,
- some `pre` inside a line,
- more than one `pre` inside a line,
- a `pre` over more than one line and even
- a `pre` starting in a line where the previous `pre` ended.

All those cases are in this example file:

```
<x>    </x>
<pre>_ _</pre>
_ <pre>_</pre> _<x>    </x>_
_ <pre>_</pre> _<x>    </x> _ <pre>_</pre> _
_ <pre>_<x>    </x>_
_</pre> _
_<x>    </x>_<x>    </x>_
_ <pre>_
_<x>    </x>_<x>    </x>_
_</pre> _ <pre>
_
<x>    </x>_
</pre>
```

To avoid multiple implementation of the minification part, let's separate `pre` and non-`pre` linewise in a first pass:

```
sed -z -e 's/<pre>/\n&/g;s_</pre>_&\n_g'
```

(You are obviously using GNU `sed`, otherwise your `:a;N;$!ba;` would not work. But for GNU `sed`, you can drop that code and use option `-z` instead.)
Now this code adds a line break before each `<pre>` and after each `</pre>`. Piping that to a second `sed` gives us much less cases to care for (and line breaks do no harm outside `<pre>`).

```
sed -e '\_<pre>.*</pre>_b' -e '/<pre>/,\_</pre>_!s/>\s*</></g'
```

The first part jumps to the end of the script for lines with single-line `pre` content; the second part does the minification dummy for the remaining lines, except (`!`) for multi-line `pre`s.

Together,

```
sed -z -e 's/<pre>/\n&/g;s_</pre>_&\n_g' file.html | sed -e '\_<pre>.*</pre>_b' -e '/<pre>/,\_</pre>_!s/>\s*</></g'
```

produces

```
<x></x>

<pre>_ _</pre>

_ 
<pre>_</pre>
 _<x></x>_
_ 
<pre>_</pre>
 _<x></x> _ 
<pre>_</pre>
 _
_ 
<pre>_<x>    </x>_
_</pre>
 _
_<x></x>_<x></x>_
_ 
<pre>_
_<x>    </x>_<x>    </x>_
_</pre>
 _ 
<pre>
_
<x>    </x>_
</pre>
```

and – voilá – spaces removed outside `pre`, but untouched inside.

Comment: Replacing `s/o/O/g` with `s@>\s*<@><@g` makes it stop working - no whitespace removed ...  Using `s/o/O/g` works as expected, but it's useless.. 

The last part of your sed command doesn't use `-z`, so will also fail to handle removing `\n`, as I understand it..  

What would go in the last part if something like `s@>\n*\s*\n*<@><@g` won't work?

Did you actually test minifying any HTML using your example, or just changing "o"s to "O"s?

Comment: My dictonary doesn't know your definition of "minify", but this code can do anything on lines outside `pre`. If it's about removal of spaces between tags (looks equally useless to me), my example didn't fail, it just didn't contain anything to be removed (-;  I changed the example accordingly.

Comment: My definition of "html minification" is quite standard, I think - removal of leading whitespace, trailing whitespace for each line, then removal of newlines... with the added caveat that I want the contents of `<pre>` tags ignored, cos that is their purpose .. Sorry if I am not being clear, but it should be easy to see what I mean by looking at the first `sed` command in my OP - the output does what I need, EXCEPT it does not ignore the contents of `<pre>` tags..